# Is it possible to transform python classes to cassandra object-model?

Tags: python, cassandra

I have following python class:

```
class Pet(Model):
  def __init__(self, id: int=None, name: str=None):
    self._id = id
    self._name = name
```

This python class was generated from a swagger spec. I want to transform this class to a corresponding cassandra object-model to be able to persist it. Cassandra object-model should look like:

```
class Pet(Model):
  id = UUID(primary_key=True)
  name = Text()
```

What is the best way to do it automatically knowing that I have a huge amount of classes to presist?